# How can I delete every single letter of a row after a certain character in R?

Tags: r, gsub

I am having a problem doing a cleaning of transactions. I have an excel with every single transaction that clients do, with the number, the gloss and the code of the industry. I convert this excel in text separated by ";" then I only need to clean the gloss and convert it back again into an excel.

```
tolower(tabla1)
lapply(tabla1, tolower)
tabla1[] <- lapply(tabla1, tolower)
str(tabla1)
tabla1
tabla1_texto <- gsub("[.]", "", tabla1)
table1_texto <- gsub("[(]", " ", tabla1_texto)
```

I know that I need to use `gsub()` but I'm not sure how to use it, in other hand, someone know how to do a correct dictionary and only keep certain words and delete every other word?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include an example of a typical string you will encounter, the desired output, and the logic to get you there.

Comment: The questions in your title and post below do not seem to match. In the title you ask how to delete characters in a row after a certain character. While in the post you are asking how to delete certain words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a string like this one:

```
string <- "Some text here; and some text here; and some more text here"
```

Then you can delete everything after the first `;` with:

```
gsub(";.*$", "", string)
[1] "Some text here"
```

Explanation of `;,*$` which you will be substituting for `""` (empty string):

- starting with `;`
- any character `.` zero or more times `*`
- up until the end of the line `$`

If you have a table - you will have to do this for every row separately.